# Turning each entry in a Dataframe into a Class?

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a 40k battle simulator in Python for practice, and I have a table of datasheets as follows:

```
|              Unit              | M | WS | BS | S | T | W | A | Ld | Save |  
| Chaos Lord                     | 5 |  2 |  2 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 4 |  9 |    2 |  
| Master of Possession           | 6 |  3 |  3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 |  9 |    3 |  
| Chaos Space Marine             | 6 |  3 |  3 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 |  7 |    3 |
```

I figured making a class for Units is the easiest way to calculate hits/wounds/etc during "combat", but making an instance for each unit seems very tedious. I created a class, and each column is a variable in the class. Is there way to make a for loop to turn each row into an instance of said class and fill in the variables from the columns?

I've tried the code below, but I can obviously see why it doesn't work. Just wondering if there's a way to make it work.

```
for x in Units.Unit:
x = Model(x, x.M, x.BS, x.S, x.T, x.W, x.A, x.LD, x.Save)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Answer (score 1):

If the parameters of your `Model.__init__` method have the same names as your DataFrame columns, you can do something like this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

data = DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]})

class Model(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):

        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


models = []
for _, row in data.iterrows():
    models.append(Model(**row.to_dict()))
```